# Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js

Frontend development not being my strong suite, I'm stuck on something I feel is probably obvious.

I'm trying to load one set of nodes from a JSON file, which works, but when I'm adding new nodes from another JSON-file it throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at updateStyle (cytoscape.min.js:27)
at a.c.restore (cytoscape.min.js:27)
at a (cytoscape.min.js:27)
at u.add (cytoscape.min.js:27)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (?q=:42)
at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

Is it some sort of conflict? Faulty code?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.1.4/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #cy {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

            var data = $.getJSON('example.json');
            var data2 = $.getJSON('example2.json');

            var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
                container: document.getElementById('cy'),
                elements: data,

                style: [{
                    // This is now essentially your default for the graph
                    selector: 'node',
                    style: {
                        'background-color': '#666',
                        'label': 'data(id)'
                    }
                }],
                layout: {
                    name: 'grid'
                }
            });

            cy.add({
                data: data2
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

example.json:

```
[
{
  "data": { "id": "a"  }
},
{
  "data": { "id": "b" }
},
{
  "data": { "id": "ab", "source": "a", "target": "b" }
}
]
```

example2.json:

```
[
{
  "data": { "id": "c" }
},
{
  "data": { "id": "d" }
},
{
  "data": { "id": "ac", "source": "a", "target": "c" }
}
]
```

Comment: I bet `data` and `data2` don't contain what you think they do. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON

Comment: ^ They contain Deferred objects / the jqXHR object, probably not what you wanted in your object

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, Cytoscape allows you to specify promises (anything with a thennable interface) for elements and style at init.  Init can be async anyway, because some layouts are async.

Graph operations are not going to allow you to pass in promises.  That would make all basic operations async, and that would make things overcomplicated for users.

If you're not familiar with promises, take a look at the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

E.g. `promise.then( resolvedValue => doSomethingWith( resolvedValue ) );`